# How to target this component HTML attribute, is there a easier way to get this element?

Tags: angular, typescript, input, components, this

How to target **'this'** component html attribute elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.content-img') ?

is there a better way than doing nativeElement.querySelector?

I've a component and an input.

From the input I target the component function that is **imgChange()** 
In imgChange() i would like to target that component element **''** and **get .offsetWidth**

app.ts

```
<image-component #Img format="png"></image-component>
<input (change)="Img.imgChange($event)" type="file">
```

image-component.ts

```
@Component({
  template: `
       <ng-content></ng-content>
      <div class="content-img"></div>

})
export class ResizingCroppingImagesComponent{
  public elementRef; 
    public _format = 'jpeg';
    public img = null;
    public sizeW = 230;
    public sizeH = 150;
    public sizeWmax = 720;
    public sizeHmax = 720;
    public stateMouse = false;
    public stateType = 'none';
    public stateR = 'none';
    public centerX = 0;
    public centerY = 0;
    public percent = 100;
    public imgUrl = null;
    public _top = 0;
    public _left = 0;
    public _img = {};
    public _src = null;

    public imgDataUrl;
    public origImg;
    public imgWidth;
    public imgHeight;

imgChange(event) {

  const _this = this;
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = ev => { }

  _this._left = (_this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.content-img').offsetWidth / 2) -  _this.imgWidth / 2;

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ViewChild. In your situation you shoul do like

```
@Component({
  template: `
       <ng-content></ng-content>
      <div #contentImg class="content-img"></div>

})
```

and in your class declare a local variable with ViewChild annotation,

```
@ViewChild('contentImg') contentImg;
```